# Delayed_Job - Rake jobs:work vs. script/delayed_job start - issue with route urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, delayed-job

I am running Rake 0.9.2, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.9, and Delayed_Job 2.1.4 and I am trying to figure out why when I run the following

RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start - Everything runs fine

RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake jobs:work - I get this {You can no longer call ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options directly. You need to set config.action_mailer.default_url_options. If you are using ActionMailer standalone, you need to include the routing url_helpers directly.}

I'm trying to add this to my welcome.html.erb message

```
<p><%= link_to "#{new_user_session_url(:subdomain => @account.subdomain)}", new_user_session_url(:subdomain => @account.subdomain) %></p>
```

Comment: Can you show how you are setting config.action_mailer.default_url_options

Comment: development.rb -> config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "lvh.me:3000" }

Comment: i have a url_helper.rb too that I'm using the default_url_options to help with Devise and subdomains

Comment: Nowhere is any of your mailers doing something like default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port? Sometimes gems you're including will do this.

Comment: betamatt, I am not but will add whatever I need to make it happen.  It is very confusing why it happens one way and not the other.  Both should load the rails environment.  I can change my default_url_options to have the :host and :port option if you think that might help

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you need to. Do you have a stacktrace? (try running rake with --trace to get more details)

Comment: I don't but will try to get one.  I have seen that the issue I'm having might go away with ActionMailer with Request gem. I wish I didn't need to add a gem might have too tho.

Comment: Do you think i need to require libraries that I'm missing

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace to the error.